# PHP File upload name to a sql table

Tags: php, file, file-upload

I am trying to allow for file upload and then writing the name of that file into a SQL table so it can be displayed. My form looks like this:

```
<form class="addProduct" name="addNewProduct" action="add_product.php" method="GET">
<div class="form-group">
<label for="productImgName">Image:</label>
<input type="file" id="productImgName" name="productImgName">
<p class="help-block">This will be re-sized</p>
</div>
</form>
```

And then the PHP file is:

```
$target = "images/";
$target = $target . basename( $_FILES['productImgName']['name']);

$Filename=basename( $_FILES['productImgName']['name']);


 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['productImgName']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['productImgName']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";

mysqli_query("INSERT INTO products (productImgName)
VALUES ('$Filename')") ;
} else {
//Gives and error if its not
echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
}
```

It won't upload and Im not sure why.

Comment: Are you getting any of the error messages in your PHP file?

Comment: No errors in the file no

Comment: Also, take a look at this website: http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp. Take a look at the form tag. It has the enctype attribute. Go through that website and try to do an example following what w3schools says

Comment: Are you aware of the code-injection vulnerability here? http://symcbean.blogspot.co.uk/2016/06/local-file-inclusion-why-everything-you.html

Comment: Yea dude this was a very old question. I'm past that now. Thanks for the comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two issues with your form element:

- You cannot use the GET method to upload files
- You need to specify the `enctype` attribute

  ```
  <form class="addProduct" name="addNewProduct" action="add_product.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
  ```

[Documentation](https://secure.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php).

Also note that the filename is user input and should be treated as such. Sanitize it before adding it to your query or use prepared statements.

Comment: Thank you, that was the problem. I appreciate the reply!